# Difference between lims and expand_limits

Tags: r, ggplot2

I don't know what difference is below

```
library(ggplot2)
sp <- ggplot(cars, aes(x = speed, y = dist)) + geom_point()
sp
sp + lims(x = c(0,NA), y = c(0,NA))
sp + expand_limits(x = 0 , y = 0)
```

When do I use `expand_limits`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the manual for the two functions:
`?lims` says:

> This is a shortcut for supplying the limits argument to the individual scales. Note that, by default, any values outside the limits will be replaced with NA.

`?expand_limits` says:

> Sometimes you may want to ensure limits include a single value, for all panels or all plots.

In addition `?lims` even forwards you to `expand_limits` :

> To expand the range of a plot to always include certain values, see expand_limits.

You can see the difference if you change the code to:

```
sp <- ggplot(cars, aes(x = speed, y = dist)) + geom_point()
sp
sp + lims(x = c(10,NA), y = c(10,NA))
sp
sp + expand_limits(x = 10 , y = 10)
sp
```

The first plot will start with 10 and 10
the second one only ensures that 10 and 10 are included, by starting at 0.

Comment: You are welcome. Can you accept the answer, so the topic is closed? :-)